# A book resting in equilibrium on a horizontal shelf and against a wall.

Tags: classical-mechanics

A book is resting in equilibrium on a horizontal shelf and against a vertical wall, and makes an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal. A horizontal force of magnitude $P$ newtons is applied at the bottom right edge of the book (half way between the front and back cover). The force $P$ acts in a vertical plane which passes through the centre of mass $G$ of the book, and is perpendicular to the wall.

The book is modelled by a uniform rectangular block of height $10$ cm and width $4$cm and a weight of $20$ N. The coefficients of friction between the book and shelf, and the book and wall are each $0.4$.

Show that the least value of $P$ needed to move the book is given by:

$$P=\frac{84\cos{\theta} + 33.6\sin{\theta}}{10\sin{\theta}-8.64\cos{\theta}}$$

Find the interval in which the value of $\theta$ must lie.

Working's out so far:

Let $S$ be the normal reaction on the wall acting in line with the centre of mass $G$ of the book. Let $F_2$ be the frictional force acting on the wall perpendicular to $S$.

Also, on the shelf, let $R$ be the normal reaction acting in line with $G$ of the book and $F_1$ be the frictional force perpendicular to $R$. I will call the weight $W$ (for now) and the horizontal force is acting on the bottom edge of the book is $P$.

Could you check/confirm the following, firstly?

Resolving horizontally:

$$Scosθ + F_1sinθ = F_2sinθ + Rcosθ + P$$

Resolving vertically:

$$ Ssinθ + F_1cosθ + W = F_2cosθ + Rsinθ$$

Taking moments about $G$ ($S$ and $R$ act along the line of action of $G$, so do not appear in the moment equation):

$$5Scosθ +  5Pcosθ = 5F_1sinθ + 5F_2sinθ$$

Clockwise moments = anti-clockwise moments.

Also, $F_1=μR$ and $F_2=μS$, where $μ=0.4$.

Comment: How is the force applied horizontally and act in the vertical plane?

Comment: This means that the only movement possible is along the shelf and up (or down) the wall i.e. vertical movement. There will be no sideways movement (which would be in the horizontal plane). So, for example, the book would never fall off the shelf.